# Proper use of Collections

Tags: php, mysql, product-collection

So I am new to collections and messing with the DB directly. I have my collection pulling the data that I need but now im not sure what direction to go in.

My problem is that I don't know what to do with the collection. Are collections just used to generate the SQL and then you call a query to manipulate the data? Or would one copy the data from the collection to an array?

I only need the sku and one other attribute. I tried copying the collection to an array using  `$collection->getColumnValues()`. Using this it will only pull one attribute. What I would like is to have an array with both attributes needed.

I just am not sure how to properly use the data in collections.

The end goal is to use the data from the collection to search and pull data from a DB and write it out to a csv file.

Any help would be appreciated and can provide clarity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Magento's CRUD models have three basic class types.

A "model" is what you'll most commonly use.  This represents data of a particular type in a database agnostic way (product, category, CMS Page, Review, etc.)

A "resource model" is a class that, behind the scenes, does the actual fetching of data from Magento. Every *model* has a *resource model* that is used to load a single instance of a *model* from the database.

A "collection" is a class that loads an array like structure of multiple models based on a set of rules.  Think of it like a SQL `WHERE clause`.

Confusing things somewhat is, behind the scenes, Magento **also** considers a collection to be a resource model.  So there's *collection resource models* and *individual resource models*.

Generally speaking, when you want to load a specific item, you use a *model*.  When you want to load a number of items, you use a *collection resource model*.

```
//loads one
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

//loads many products where price is greater than 100
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*') //load all fields, see EAV below
->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt'=>'100'));

foreach($products as $product)
{
    var_dump($product->getSku());
}
```

One thing to keep in mind about loading via a *collection resource model* is each individual *model's* `afterLoad` method won't be called automatically, which means some data may not be loaded.

The *individua resource model* classes are usually not accessed directly.  However, occasionally a specific *model* will have a *resource* model with a useful method on it.  These you'll discover over time using the system.

Finally, there's one more distinction to be made.  Magento's regular CRUD models have a special syntax for loading via something that's not the numeric ID.  For example, here's how to load a CMS page model by title

```
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('Home page','title');
var_dump($page->getData());
```

However, a few Magento models are EAV models.  That stands for "entity attribute value", and is a fancy way of saying these models don't have a fixed set of fields.  This includes product models, and category models.  This feature is what lets you pick different attributes for different types of products.  Each field on an EAV model is known as an attribute. The above syntax won't work with these models, instead you need to use the `loadByAttribute` method.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'n2610');
```

Regarding your specific problem, if you're getting an error with the specific text "method undefined", then something is very wrong with your system.  Even if the `getSku` method doesn't exist, Magento has magic setter and getter methods  which ensure a `get` call on any *model* will always return something, even if it's null.

What's more likely is you're getting an error like the following

```
Call to a member function getSku() on a non-object
```

This error is happening because the `loadByAttribute` method returns `false` if it can't load the object.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'this-is-not-a-sku');
var_dump($product); //prints false
```

Try something like this in your code.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'sku-value);
if($product)
{
    var_dump($product->getName());
    var_dump($product->getSku());
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
else
{
    var_dump("Could not load product");
}
```

In additional to the conditional, notice the `getData()` method.  This will return an array of all the object's data as an array.

Reference : [Alan Storm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/about-collection-model-and-resource-model)