# basic php question

Tags: php, blocks, magento-2.0

Why is it not possible to call a function like this

```
$this->getCollection()->getSku();
```

And it's possible to do it with a foreach like this

```
foreach($this->getCollection() as $item)
$item -> getSku();
endforeach
```

For reference ... ( in the block folder )

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Ming\Test\Model\Test');
    $collection = $model->getCollection();

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Refer good answer by Alan http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/about-collection-model-and-resource-model/4579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento "Model Collection" is a collection of model. Model collection extend from php IteratorAggregate, Countable, ArrayInterface SPL interface. Here you can handle complex data. So when you create a collection you cant access like this

```
$this->getCollection()->getSku();
```

Because it's a collection of items, That's why you need to access such collection following way

```
foreach($this->getCollection() as $item) {
    $item -> getSku();
}
```

Learn more from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-8.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it up, Anyway if let's say i am going to place an IF conditions like this.

if($this->getCollection()->getSku() == ABC123 ){

}

I can't possibly use a foreach statement here. what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: In this case why you create collection? You can do it by model.